# Macbook: Mini-DVI to DVI + DVI to VGA works?

Tags: display, macbook, vga, dvi, mini-dvi

I have a Macbook 2,1 late 2007 and I'm wondering if it's possible to use a Mini-DVI to DVI adapter combined with a DVI to VGA adapter to use a VGA Monitor as a second display screen.

Someone has tried?

Answer (score 0):

I have the 2 cables needed for this and upon testing the 2 cables together hooked up to my computer and a screen it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

So long as the DVI adapters are both DVI-A it should work. If one is DVI-D it's less likely, unless it performs D-A conversion.

It would be a safer bet to just get a Mini-DVI to VGA. There are ones listed specifically for MacBooks, if you just Google "Mini-DVI to VGA adapter"

Comment: Nobody wants DVI-A. Instead, Mini-DVI to DVI-I is a realistic option. Naturally, everything Mini-DVI is for MacBooks, because no one else ever used this connector.